# Is there a single word that encapsulates both attendance and punctuality?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm creating a report that contains both, whether a person showed up and, their tardiness.

I'm thinking I might be able to just call it an attendance report, but I don't know if that also implies that it keeps track of their punctuality.

Comment: *Punctuality* implies attendance.

Comment: But you can be punctual and have a poor attendance: a kid who's missing a lot of schooldays due to sickness can still be punctual when he attends. And the opposite too: you can never miss a workday, but be always late too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve spent a lot of time working on similar reports! **Adherence** or **Compliance** are some of the more common terms I’ve seen used, where punctuality and attendance are key performance indicators that you’re measuring. Your suggestion of attendance is perfectly workable too.

Ultimately the best option to go with is the one that’s already in common use by people who will be reading the report. If the report is used to generate actions (such as an employee receiving a warning) then the wording in supporting documentation for that may provide useful detail.

Finally, after much thought the closest I could come to something that covers both punctuality and attendance is the following phrase:

> **Regular as clockwork:** Very regularly; repeatedly and predictably.
>
> [[Reference: Cambridge Dictionary]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/as-regular-as-clockwork)

Not a single word, but if used to describe a person’s attendance I feel it well covers both punctuality and attendance.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!